# R-modules over a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^3$, $A$ be the matrix with column vectors $e3, e1, e2$ (where $e1, e2, e3$ are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$). $R = \mathbb{F}[X]$. Let $V_a = V$ be the R module where addition is defined by using vector space addition in V and multiplication is defined by $(a_mX^m + ... + a_1X + a_0)\vec{v} = a_m(A^m\vec{v}) + ... a_1(A \vec{v}) + a_0 \vec{v} $ .

Show that there are only three R-submodules of $V_a$ that are one dimensional as $\mathbb{C}$ vector spaces. Show that $V_a$ is a cyclic submodule.

I don't understand what this question is asking, if someone has the time can you guide me through step by step, or give a similar example, because I don't even understand the problem.

Comment: Have you looked up the relevant definitions? What part of the question do you not understand?

Comment: There seem to be three different fields in this problem, I suspect they're all supposed to be $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I know its a fundamental part, but I don't understand how an R-module looks in context. The definition says what properties an r-module satisfies, so given one I could (almost always) prove it is one, but I don't know how to go about finding one?